# Netbeans Platform's toolbars are black when launching from inside IntelliJ

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea, netbeans-platform

I am currently trying to port one of my applications over to the Netbeans Platform. Since I am an IntelliJ user, I prefer to work with my favourite IDE - and luckily there are tutorials for that.

After setting up everything I need, building the first test application (empty window) I wanted to go ahead and launch my app from inside IntelliJ. As this sadly is not as easy as it might sound (or I didnt find any other way yet) I followed [this tutorial](http://netbeans.dzone.com/using-maven-and-intellij-idea) and created the following "Starter" class:

```
/**
 * Represents a starter for the Netbeans platform.
 *
 * The original code of this modified class can be found at
 * <a href="http://netbeans.dzone.com/using-maven-and-intellij-idea">this article</a>.
 */
public class NetbeansStarter {
    private static final String BRANDING = "swordsmith";
    private static final String WORKDIR = "application" + File.separatorChar + "target";
    private static final String USER = WORKDIR + File.separatorChar + "userdir";
    private static final String HOME = WORKDIR + File.separatorChar + BRANDING + File.separatorChar + "platform";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Cleanup the user's cache (otherwise problems arise, cache seems to be not written correctly).
        deleteRecursive(new File(USER, "var" + File.separatorChar + "cache"));

        // Set some system properties
        System.setProperty("netbeans.logger.console", "true"); // for logging on the console
        System.setProperty("netbeans.user", USER); // settings are stored here
        System.setProperty("netbeans.home", HOME); // Netbeans cluster
        System.setProperty("sun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize", "true"); // maven sets this per default on starting

        // Build new arguments list
        final List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList("--branding", BRANDING));
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));

        Main.main(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    private static void deleteRecursive(File pPath) {
        if (!pPath.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        File[] files = pPath.listFiles();
        if (files == null) {
            return ;
        }

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) deleteRecursive(file);
            else file.delete();
        }
    }

}
```

However, upon launch I am being presented with this screen which clearly shows what's wrong with it:

[image: The background color of the toolbars is black]

Is there something I've missed? Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to fix this by just upgrading to the 802 version of netbeans platform. seems like this was an issue and has been fixed!